# Using closures to delegate running callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a module where I have a function that takes a callback, and inside of it calls another function that also takes a callback, similar to this

`function doSomething(params..., callback){
           //Do some work
           someOtherFunction(params.., callback2)
           //...???
 }`

The way I have it is that doSomething() is an entry point to a module that encapsulates some logic specific to a certain task and communicates with other components through doSomething()'s callback parameter, inside someOtherFunction() it can also call other functions that take other callbacks.

is it possible -and if so is it a good practice- to use closures to wrap the first callback provided to doSomething() and the second provided to someOtherFunction() using a closure in a way similar to this:

```
`function wrapCallbacks(err_cb2, arg_to_callback_2){
          function callback(err, res){
                   //first callback logic
          }
          function callback2(err, res){
                   //second callback logic
                   callback(err, res)
          }
          callback2(err_cb2, arg_to_callback_2)
}`
```

and provide this function as a callback to someOtherFunction(), and inside it can do the same to other callbacks if required, so that the callbacks would be executed in a sort of 'last-in-first-out' order, so that I can have the first callback executed after the entire module finishes it's work?

PS: I'm a novice javascript programmer, I would really appreciate pointers to any apparent misconception in my understanding of javascript.

I'm working on my final year project where i'm trying to build a peer-to-peer system that allows developers to build distributed peer-to-peer applications in a manner close to regular client-server SPAs and REST-based apps , I'm trying to implement this by building a local server that will listen for requests coming from the browser on the local machine -requests that are client-server based in nature, similar to RESTful APIs-, and transform them into messages that retrieve and store data and provide it as a result to the first API call initiated by the browser.

I'm using a layered architecture to seperate responsibilities and provide layers of abstraction, and the function in question sendMessage_interface() is an entry point to the last layer of the stack -the one responsible for resolving peer IDs into sockets to use for communication-, so this function would take a parameter like 'ID' from the user, perform some database operations to retrieve the associated IP -by calling a resolveID() function-, the resolveID() function would take a callback and provide it's result -the peer socket- as an argument, however the sendMessage_interface() function was also provided a callback by the upper layer to be executed after the response is recieved from the other peer, that's why I need it to be executed 'LIFO'

```
`this.comms_gateway_sendMessage_interface = function({destID, data, 
resolveID, checkMessageObject, callback}){

    if(!(destID && data && resolveID && callback) ||
    !(typeof(destID) === 'number') ||
    !(typeof(resolveID) === 'function') ||
    !(typeof(callback) === 'function'))
    {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid or missing Argument');
    };
    if(checkMessageObject && typeof(checkMessageObject) === 'function'){
        checkMessageObject(data);
    };

    resolveID({ID : destID, data : data, callback : wrapCallback });
};`
```

Comment: This would result in callback hell, could you provide some background of what you're actually trying to implement and why exactly you need LIFO for callback execution.

Comment: @TGW added more information through an edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks hilight a major feature of JavaScript. The fact that functions are data makes it easy to use functions as arguments of other functions. In the trade, this is often referred to a a higher-order function.

Closures are another major feature:

- Inner functions inherit the scope of the outer function, which makes managing variable scope much easier
- In cases where the outer function has completed, but the inner function is yet to run, the outer scope variables are retained, so their data can be used when the inner function runs.

The closure features are *only* available when the inner function is *defined* inside the outer function. Referencing a function inside another is not enough to make the closure variables available. We say that JavaScript has **lexical** scope: scope is defined strictly where the code is defined.

Working with multiple callbacks is always going to be awkward. If it is not necessary to persist closure variables, you can do something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(fn1,1000);

function fn1() {
    alert('one');
    window.setTimeout(fn2,1000);
}
function fn2() {
    alert('two');
    window.setTimeout(fn3,1000);
}
function fn3() {
    alert('three');
}
```

No nesting is involved, and it is completely maintainable.

If, however, you want to use data from one function in the next, the next function will need to be *inside* the first function to have access to its variables:

```
window.setTimeout(fn1,1000);

function fn1() {
    var data=0;
    alert(`data ${++data}`);
    window.setTimeout(fn2,1000);
    function fn2() {
        alert(`data ${++data}`);
        window.setTimeout(fn3,1000);
    }
    function fn3() {
        alert(`data ${data++}`);
    }
}
```

It gets worse if the third function needs to use data generated by the second function:

```
window.setTimeout(fn1,1000);

function fn1() {
    var data=0;
    alert(`data ${++data}`);
    window.setTimeout(fn2,1000);
    function fn2() {
        var stuff=3;
        alert(`data ${++data + stuff}`);
        window.setTimeout(fn3,1000);
        function fn3() {
            alert(`data ${++data + stuff}`);
        }
    }
}
```

This is lovingly referred to as **callback** hell, and you can understand why it’s to be avoided if possible. However, it is the only way a callback can benefit from closure variables — if the function is defined inside the other.

So, the short answer is yes, it is possible, and yes, it is good practice insofar as it is the only traditional way to do this sort of thing.

More modern JavaScript has an alternative called promises: they allow you to chain callback functions rather than nest them, so you have code that can be written in a more linear fashion.

Comment: this cleared a lot of misconceptions I had, thank you. I'm currently in the process of learning promises, so if you could help me with it, in the example you used, using the promises approach would look like this: fn1() would have code that performs this `fn2().then(function fn3(){//logic}).catch(err)` then fn2() would add it's own 'links' in the **middle** of the chain, is that correct?

Comment: @hmoho The short answer is yes, but give me a day or so to rework the example. I should also mention that an alternative to using closure variables is to pass them as parameters. That’s tricky in the traditional callback approach, but you can use the `bind` method to generate a new function complete with new parameters. Using promises makes that part more straightforward.

Comment: @Manngo It's very easy to pass variables and data from one function to another without callback hell - use `setTimeout(() => myFn(data1, data2), 1000)`, for example, not tricky at all.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I am aware of that, though your sample code won’t work in older versions of IE. I was using `setTimeout` as an easy example of using a callback, rather than setting up a more elaborate sample with Ajax, loading images, or JavaScript animation. The point is this is where callback hell comes from.